C# items that don't follow rest of interface
I'm working on a game with unity, and I've created a state manager for the in-game state of certain organisms. Each state implements a ISimpleStateManager interface, but some have unique behavior and need to do different things when their state is updated:
interface IOrganismStateManager {
  void SetIdle();
  void SetRunning(float dir);
  void SetCarryingItem(Item item);
}

enum OrganismtState {
  idle,
  running,
  carryingItem,
}

class OrganismStateManager : IOrganismStateManager {
  Dictionary<OrganismtState, ISimpleStateManager> _states = new Dictionary<OrganismtState, ISimpleStateManager>() {
    { OrganismtState.idle, new SimpleStateManager() },
    { OrganismtState.running, new RunningStateManager() },
    { OrganismtState.carryingItem, new CarryingItemStateManager() },
  }

  public void SetIdle() {
    _states[OrganismtState.idle].SetActive(true);
  }

  public void SetRunning(float dir) {
    var stateManager = _states[OrganismtState.running];
    stateManager.SetActive(true);
    var runningManager = (RunningStateManager) stateManager;
    runningManager.SetDirection(dir);
  }

  public void SetCarryingItem(Item item) {
    var stateManager = _states[OrganismtState.carryingItem];
    stateManager.SetActive(true);
    var runningManager = (CarryingItemStateManager) stateManager;
    runningManager.SetCarriedItem(item);
  }
}

interface ISimpleStateManager {
  void SetActive(bool active);
}

class SimpleStateManager : ISimpleStateManager {
  protected bool _active = false;

  public virtual void SetActive(bool active) {
    _active = active;
  }
}

class RunningStateManager : SimpleStateManager, ISimpleStateManager {
  float _direction;

  public void SetDirection(float dir) {
    _direction = dir;
  }
}

class CarryingItemStateManager : SimpleStateManager, ISimpleStateManager {
  Item _carriedItem;

  public void SetCarriedItem(Item item) {
    _carriedItem = item;
  }
}

The solution I've landed on is to cast the interface type to the concrete class type for a given state manager, and then call a method on it directly.
I can think of a few other solutions, but I wanted to know if there's a best-practice approach to this kind of situation.

is it mandatory to have each state in a class ? as I don't see a logic that required to be encapsulated into a separate class. not sure what drove you to use encapsulation while it can be much simpler with one class.

@iSR5 its not mandatory, but these things tend to get real complex real fast and I've found if I dont do basic encapsulation early on, the code turns messy

If you have to cast to concrete type then that is a code smell. Why have the state managers in a dictionary?
Instead of a dictionary you can create another class to hold the state objects
public class OrganismStates
{
    public SimpleStateManager Idle { get; } = new SimpleStateManager();
    public RunningStateManager Running { get; } = new RunningStateManager();
    public CarryingItemStateManager CarryingItem { get; } = new CarryingItemStateManager();
}

Then remove the dictionary and use the new class.
public class OrganismStateManager
{
    private OrganismStates _states = new OrganismStates();
    
    public void SetIdle()
    {
        _states.Idle.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void SetRunning(float dir)
    {
        var stateManager = _states.Running;
        stateManager.SetActive(true);
        stateManager.SetDirection(dir);
    }

    public void SetCarryingItem(Item item)
    {
        var stateManager = _states.CarryingItem;
        stateManager.SetActive(true);
        stateManager.SetCarriedItem(item);
    }
}

No boxing, no casting. Still have the classes implement the interface so they can be passed generic methods that take the interface when not needing concert methods.
Unit test will be a bit more complex but no more than the current implementation

With pattern matching you can avoid explicit casting:
class OrganismStateManager : IOrganismStateManager {
  Dictionary<OrganismState, ISimpleStateManager> _states = new() {
    { OrganismState.idle, new SimpleStateManager() },
    { OrganismState.running, new RunningStateManager() },
    { OrganismState.carryingItem, new CarryingItemStateManager() },
  };

  public void SetIdle() 
    => SetState(OrganismState.idle, string.Empty);

  public void SetRunning(float dir) 
    => SetState(OrganismState.running, dir);

  public void SetCarryingItem(Item item) 
    => SetState(OrganismState.carryingItem, item);

  private void SetState(OrganismState organismState, object customState) {
    ISimpleStateManager stateManager = _states[organismState];
    stateManager.SetActive(true);
    Action update = stateManager switch
    {
        RunningStateManager running when customState is float dir => () => running.SetDirection(dir),
        CarryingItemStateManager carrying when customState is Item item => () => carrying.SetCarriedItem(item),
        SimpleStateManager simple => () => {},
        _ => () => { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    };
    update();
  }
}

Please bear in mind that there are trade-off as well

Possible boxing and unboxing of the parameter (for example in case of float dir)
Possibility to pass (unintentionally) incompatible customState parameter >> NotSupportedException
Possibility to forgot to update SetState after extending the _states collection >> NotSupportedException


Nice call! I was twisting my brain trying to use CRTP to solve it.

@JesseC.Slicer Thanks :). My first thought was to use Visitor pattern but it would add some complexity to this otherwise simple use case.
